# Copy result from powershell to another file

Tags: powershell

I made query:

```
gwmi Win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Where-Object {$_.ipaddress -like "*192.168.3*"} | Select-Object -Property SettingID | Format-Wide
```

As a result, I get for example:

```
{CD4FCC20-30E3-4E2E-8F8A-556833287B3C}
```

How to copy the string `{CD4FCC20-30E3-4E2E-8F8A-556833287B3C}` to an existing file in piece "\Device\" between \ and "

Comment: Is `"\Device\"` the only contents of the file? Could you show us a sample file?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
    
    `$adapter = gwmi Win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Where-Object {$_.ipaddress -like "192.168.3"} | Select-Object -expandProperty SettingID
    $path = "c:\ProgramData\Triangle MicroWorks\IEC 61850 Suite\Hammer\Hammer_Clients.cnfg"
    $word = "{}"
    $replacement = "$adapter"
    $text = get-content $path 
    $newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
    $newText > $path`